# MarkLogic - Extending the Search, return specific object node

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am very new getting started with MarkLogic and XQuery.

I am trying to create a `Search Transform` to return, the **actual JSON from a specific level of the document**

Here is a sample Document.

[image]

I would like to return the whole JSON based `segment` no matter where the search results are in the lower level (transcript, topics, banners etc.,)

---

Splashing around in the Query Console...

`search:search('trump')/search:result/search:snippet//@path`

Successfully Returns the `path` of the object, wrapped in a fn:doc

> fn:doc("/20170120/NBCNightlyNews/1830/nbc")/array-node("segments")/object-node()[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty07s.png)/transcript/node("00:00:02")/text("message")

However,

When I try to implment a similar Xpath Expression in a transform.

```
let $root := $content/*
return document {$root/search:result/search:snippet//@path}
```

And try to execute it (at no matter what the xpath expression is, besides simply $root itself there is a different failure) it returns

```
<error-response xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/error">
<status-code>400</status-code>
<status>Bad Request</status>
<message-code>XDMP-CHILDNODEKIND</message-code>
<message>
XDMP-CHILDNODEKIND: $root/search:result/search:snippet/descendant-or-self::node()/@path -- document nodes cannot have attribute node children
</message>
</error-response>
```

If I can get the transform to return the path, I can then continue on trying to evaluate the path, grab the appropriate JSON section and return.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've written [a REST API service extension](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions) to do searches. If so, consider using the [/v1/search](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/search) endpoint instead -- that way you're using the built-in functionality.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do: do you want to return snippets from the "segment" part of the document, or do you want to return that complete part of the document, regardless of where the matches were?

If the former, you can [customize the snippeting](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/search#id_10158) by specifying the preferred source of matches.

If the latter, you can write [a search transform](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/search#id_94556) that will give you complete control over what gets returned.

These options are available (and I think the same) whether using the REST API or calling the Search API.

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you for your response. I was previously using the `/v1/search` but will eventually need to customize the search further (we are using a content analysis server that will provide weights which we will need to incorporate in search, which is why I started into the extension. I believe I need to research the Transforms a little, and then circle back to the custom search logic. I will circle back after I read the suggested docs

Comment: Depending on your final goal, you might also want to look at the extract-document-data option, which enables you to extract selected portions of the matched document. http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_37692

Comment: As Dave and Kim hint, you can use the Search API within your resource service extension, which will give you snippeting and XPath-based extraction.

Comment: I have updated my question, trying to achieve this with a transform, I am going to start researching extract-document-data option now as well. Thank you for all the guidance

Comment: It looks like extraction is more applicable to my task than transform I think, Thank you for the tip @kcoleman

Comment: I will open a new question for subsequent questions on extraction. I will accept this answer as the answer and its comments have guided me in a direction that appears suitable