# MarkLogic - REST API Service Extension - Search Extraction Option

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have the following JSON Documents in a MarkLogic DB

[image]

I am attempting to write a custom search extension, so that I can return the full segment JSON, for which a match is found. The other Segments of the Array should not be returned, if the matches were not found within that segment.

With Help from a previous thread ( [MarkLogic - Extending the Search, return specific object node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260518/marklogic-extending-the-search-return-specific-object-node) for reference )

I learned about the `<extract-document-data>` option for the `search:search` module.

However, when I use that option, It returns me **All** Segments in the document, regardless of which segment actually had the matches.

Here is my code

```
declare
function ext:get(
  $context as map:map,
  $params  as map:map
) as document-node()*
{

  map:put($context, "output-types", "application/json"),
  map:put($context, "output-status", (200, "OK")),

  let $search-term := map:get($params, "searchTerm")
  let $query := search:search($search-term, 
        <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
            <extract-document-data>
                <extract-path>/segments</extract-path>
            </extract-document-data>
            <return-facets>true</return-facets>
        </options>
    )

  return document {$query} 
};
```

Doing This However, extracts **All** Segments from the document, and not just the ones that have the matches. I have not been able to find subsequent options for "match only" type of modifier.

Is there anyway to only extract the "segment" of the match, and not all segments

### Essentially I am trying to get the raw json of the highlighted part [image]

Update: attempting custom snippet

```
declare
function ext:my-snippet(
    $result as node(),
    $ctsquery as schema-element(cts:query),
    $options as element(search:transform-results)?
) as element(search:snippet)
{
    element search:snippet {
        $result
    }
};

  let $query := search:search($search-term,
    <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
        <transform-results apply="my-snippet" ns="ext" at="/show-search.xqy">
            <max-snippet-chars>150</max-snippet-chars>
            <per-match-tokens>20</per-match-tokens>
        </transform-results>

    </options>
    )
```

Deployment for the above module works fine. All code is in same file called `show-search.xqy` However When I try to hit the URL, it returns

> Invalid Request: reason: Extension show-search does not exist

If I go back to default snippet option, it works fine. Only fails with custom snippet.

ANy thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried setting searchable-expression in your options to something beneath the document root?  Also, have you tried walking through matches using search:highlight?  Also, have you considered a custom snippet function? https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_61707 Or a custom decorator? https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_66810

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the properties that matched the query, you could take a look at snippeting:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_65347

You may need to write a custom snippetter to do what you want:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_61707

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Hi @ehennum thanks for your response. I am investigating custom snippeting right now. Adding the `transform-results apply="snippet"` works. However when I try to add a custom snippet that simply returns `$result` It  deploys fine, but returns a `500 internal server` stating that my extension does not exist. I will update my question with my `transform-result` code

Answer (score 0):

I have personally often found it more straight-forward to use transforms instead of extract-document-data when my data model is complex or I want to have some specific logic to pare down my results to the only the data points I want.

A transform will handle your search result as a document and you can write some XQuery (or JavaScript) to navigate through, select the data points of interest, format a response, and return the parsed results.

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/transforms